# Mediawiki with Docker Imagemagick

Tags: docker, imagemagick, mediawiki

i want to use Imagemagick that runs inside Docker. I created a convert.sh file that runs my Imagemagick with arguments:

convert.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

IMAGE=imagemagick

ARGS=$@

exec docker run --rm -i --user="$(id -u):$(id -g)" \

-v "$PWD":/workdir \

$IMAGE /bin/bash -c \

"/usr/bin/convert $ARGS"
```

Command:

```
./convert.sh --version
```

Output:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

So my imagemagick is accessible.

Inside LocalSetting.php i added:

```
$wgUseImageMagick = true;

$wgImageMagickConvertCommand = "/path/to/my/convert.sh";
```

Sadly this isn't working. I get the error

```
Error creating the preview image: sh: 1: convert: not found
```

How can i fix that?

Comment: Where does that PHP command come from? Who runs it? How is it related to **ImageMagick**? Where's the command that caused the error message? Thank you.

Comment: Why is `"/usr/bin/convert $ARGS"` all in quotes?